# How can I get case-insensitive completion with Term::ReadLine::Gnu?

Tags: perl, readline, case-insensitive

I can't seem to get case-insensitive completion when using [Term::ReadLine::Gnu](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Term%3a%3aReadLine%3a%3aGnu).  Take this example script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use Term::ReadLine;

my $term = Term::ReadLine->new('test');
say "Using " . $term->ReadLine;

if (my $attr = $term->Attribs) {
  $term->ornaments(0);
  $attr->{basic_word_break_characters}     = ". \t\n";
  $attr->{completer_word_break_characters} = " \t\n";
  $attr->{completion_function} = \&complete_word;
} # end if attributes

my @words = qw(apple approve Adam America UPPER UPPERCASE UNUSED);

sub complete_word
{
  my ($text, $line, $start) = @_;
  return grep(/^$text/i, @words);
} # end complete_word

while (1) {
  $_ = $term->readline(']');
  last unless /\S/;             # quit on empty input
} # end while 1
```

Note that `complete_word` does case-insensitive matching.  If I run this with [Term::ReadLine::Perl](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Term%3a%3aReadLine%3a%3aPerl) (by doing `PERL_RL=Perl perl script.pl`) it works as I expect.  Typing `a<TAB><TAB>` lists all 4 words.  Typing `u<TAB><TAB>` converts `u` to `U` and lists 3 words.

When I use [Term::ReadLine::Gnu](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Term%3a%3aReadLine%3a%3aGnu) instead (`PERL_RL=Gnu perl script.pl` or just `perl script.pl`), it only does case-sensitive completion.  Typing `a<TAB>` gives `app`.  Typing `u<TAB><TAB>` doesn't list any completions.

I even have `set completion-ignore-case on` in my `/etc/inputrc`, but it still doesn't work here.  (It works fine in `bash`, though.)

Is there any way to get [Term::ReadLine::Gnu](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Term%3a%3aReadLine%3a%3aGnu) to do case-insensitive completion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would appear the problem is in the `Term::ReadLine::Gnu::XS::_trp_completion_function()` (a wrapper for the user-defined completion function).

Your matches are retrieved correctly from your `complete_word()` function, but then the following snippet from the wrapper does its own case-sensitive match:

```
for (; $_i <= $#_matches; $_i++) {
    return $_matches[$_i] if ($_matches[$_i] =~ /^\Q$text/);
}
```

where `@_matches` is the result of your `complete_word()` and `$text` is the completed text so far.

So it looks like the answer is *no*, there is no *supported* way to get `Term::ReadLine::Gnu` to do case-insensitive completion.  You would have to to override the private `Term::ReadLine::Gnu::XS::_trp_completion_function` (an ugly hack to be sure) -- or modify `XS.pm` directly (arguably an even uglier hack).

**EDIT:** `Term::ReadLine::Gnu` version used: 1.20

Comment: I've [reported this bug](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=72378) along with [a patch to fix it](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Attachment/998813/520214/completion.patch).

Comment: My patch was applied in `Term::ReadLine::Gnu` version [1.21](https://metacpan.org/changes/distribution/Term-ReadLine-Gnu).